# Struggling to use the jQuery "on" event to apply corners

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have the jQuery corner plugin applied to a class like so:

```
$(".corner").corner()
```

Works great until I refresh my screen with Ajax. I'm trying to use the new `.on()` function to apply it so that elements with that class always have rounded corners. So I tried this (CoffeeScript):

```
$("body").on "load", ".corner", ->
  $(this).corner()
```

Fail. Tried several variations of it. All failures. It can't be this hard, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think $(".corner").corner() on doc ready is much cleaner

Comment: It doesn't work if I create new elements of class .corner with dynamically without reloading the page (and thus the javascripts).

Comment: Oh I see, can't you just call .corner() after each creation? call it in the creation code

Comment: It would be best to call the plugin directly in the success of the ajax request on the newly created elements. Or better yet, use css/html for this.

Comment: That's right Huangism. I'm trying to keep my code DRY, so I'd like to have .corner() just fire in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be use [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

```
$(".corner").livequery ->
  $(this).corner()
```

Which will trigger corner() on page load as well as any newly created elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think the `load` event is triggered on the `body` on successful ajax calls.

I dunno about coffeescript, but you can use the global ajax event called [`.ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)  instead to listen for successful ajax calls, then just reapply the plugin:

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $(this).find('.corner').corner();
});
```

Note that this might result in multiple initalizations, make sure the plugin can handle that or do a check yourself.